# How to format date in PHP from phpMyAdmin database

Tags: php, date, format

I can't figure out how to format the timestamp on my database so I figured I should use my PHP code, but still cannot figure it out.

PHP CODE:

```
function filldiv() {
$loopResult .= '';
$events = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM a3825952_blog.Blog ORDER BY DATE DESC'); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($events)) { 
    $loopResult .= ' 
            <div class="blogbox show"> 
                <div class="blogtitle">'.$row['TITLE'].'</div> 
                <div class="blogdate">'.$row['DATE'].'</div>                    
                <div class="blogcontent">'.$row['CONTENT'].'</div> 
                <div class="blogimage"> <img src="../'.$row['IMAGE'].'"/></div> 
                <div class="blogimage"> <img src="../'.$row['IMAGEB'].'"/></div>
                <div class="blogimage"> <img src="../'.$row['IMAGEC'].'"/></div> 
                <div class="showHide"></div>
            </div>              
    '; 
} 
echo $loopResult;
```

Comment: What datatype is the date from your database?

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with phpMyAdmin or MySQL in general – if you've got a Unix timestamp that you want to format in PHP, look at http://www.php.net/date. For example: `print date('m/d/Y', $timestamp);` prints 11/09/2014. If it's *not* a Unix timestamp but perhaps something like a MySQL `date` column type, use the helper function `strtotime($date_from_mysql);`; see http://php.net/strtotime.

Comment: A short look into the excellent documentation would answer this. May I ask why you don't consult it?

Comment: Current(default) format on stored timestamp: 2014-10-29 09:25:18. I will review documentation and see what I can do. Desired format: October 29, 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for every ones suggestions on reading the documentation. For some odd reason I just didn't think of it. I was able to figure it out and posted the solution below. Again, thanks!

First I had to set the rows date to a variable, then format the date in the loop.

```
function filldiv() {
$loopResult .= '';
$events = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM database.table ORDER BY DATE DESC'); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($events)) { 

$date = date_create($row['DATE']);

    $loopResult .= ' 
            <div class="blogbox show"> 
                <div class="blogtitle">'.$row['TITLE'].'</div> 
                <div class="blogdate">'.date_format($date, 'l, F j, Y').'</div>                 
                <div class="blogcontent">'.$row['CONTENT'].'</div> 
                <div class="blogimage"> <img src="../'.$row['IMAGE'].'"/></div> 
                <div class="blogimage"> <img src="../'.$row['IMAGEB'].'"/></div>
                <div class="blogimage"> <img src="../'.$row['IMAGEC'].'"/></div> 
                <div class="showHide"></div>
            </div>              
    '; 
} 
echo $loopResult;
```